# Perl conditional regex with inequalities

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have one query. I have to match 2 strings in one if condition:

$release = 5.x (Here x should be greater than or equal to 3)
$version = Rx  (this x should be greater than or equal to 5 if $release is 5.3, otherwise anything is acceptable)

e.g. 5.1R11 is not acceptable, 5.3R4 is not, 5.3R5 is acceptable, and 5.4 R1 is acceptable.

I have written a code like this:

```
$release = "5.2";
$version = "R4";

if ( $release =~ /5.(?>=3)(\d)/ && $version =~ m/R(?>=5)(\d)/ )
{
    print "OK";
}
```

How can I write this?

Comment: In regex `(?>)` it means atomic grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a three-level version string, and I suggest that you use Perl's `version` facility

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use version;

my $release = '5.2';
my $version = 'R4';

if ( $version =~ /R(\d+)/ && version->parse("$release.$1") ge v5.3.5 ) {
    say 'OK';
}
```

Comment: You are always give better answer with new things.  This is called experience  :)

Comment: @Borodin Thanks a lot for answer. but I am not allowed to use any other module, as the script is already in use by some other groups in my organization. But I really got a new tool in my perl scripting knowledge.

Comment: @prateekgoyal: You could at least have tried it! The `version` pragma has been part of perl since v5.10, so you don't need to install anything. It is even loaded on demand, so you don't really need the `use version` statement.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes Borodin, I have tried it and it works very well. I also went deep into documentation of `version` and found it very helpful. And if it can be loaded on demand, great!! I am going to use it in my script. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Borodin Actually this is brilliant. I never thought it can work this simple way.

Answer (score 1):

In regex `(?>)` it means [atomic grouping.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

Group the element so it will stored into `$1` then compare the `$1` with number so it should be

```
if (( ($release =~ /5\.(\d)/) && ($1 > 3) ) && (($version =~ m/R(\d)/) && ($1 >= 3) ) )
{
    print "OK\n";
}
```

Comment: @mkHun Thanks, I got idea from your answer and got the right one after modifying it a little, Because your solution was missing some validations.

Answer (score -1):

I got the correct one after modifying mkhun's solution:

```
if ((($release =~ /5.3/)) && (($version =~ m/R(\d+)(.\d+)?/) && ($1 >= 5))
|| ((($release =~ /5.(\d)/) && ($1 > 3)) && ($version =~ m/R(\d+)(.\d+)?/)) )
{
    print "OK\n";
}
```